# Why does SLES 11 corrupts given characters?

Tags: character-encoding

If I open a notepad and copy this from it:

```
aña,
```

to a file opened with vi on the machine, I get this:

```
aÃ±a
```

**My question:** Why? What could the problem be? Logfiles on the server has the same problems. How can I verify if UTF-8 support is ""installed well"" on the SLES?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's almost certainly a multi-byte UTF-8 character getting interpreted as 2 single-byte characters in some other encoding.

The ability to show UTF-8 is more a problem on the client side than the server side. If you are running `vi` in an `xterm`, you should start the `xterm` with UTF-8 support:

```
xterm -u8 -fn '-misc-fixed-bold-r-normal--15-140-75-75-c-90-iso10646-1'
```

I confess that X11 fonts are something of a mystery to me, but the font specified above has always worked for me. Perhaps I've been lucky.

If you're using a Windows machine to run your graphics, the [PuTTY terminal emulator](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) can display UTF-8. Look in the "configuration" window, "Window" item, "Translation" sub-item. The "Received data assumed to be in which character set" pull-down menu has a "UTF-8" item.  Select it.

Comment: So it's a client-side problem on the Desktop?

Comment: @evachristine - that's my guess, due to the way that UTF-8 works, and the situation you describe as troublesome.